# Difference between return values of alloc_pages() and get_free_pages()

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

Why do we require alloc_pages() to return pointer to a struct page unlike other memory allocator function (get_free_pages(), kmalloc() ) ?
Please provide a use case.
Is it related to HIGHMEM Zone allocation?

Answer (score 4):

`alloc_pages(mask, order)`  allocates 2order pages and returns an instance of struct page to represent the start of the reserved block. alloc_page(mask) is a shorter notation for order = 0 if only one page is requested.

`__get_free_pages(mask, order) and __get_free_page(mask)` work in the same way as the
above functions but return the virtual address of the reserved memory chunk instead of a page instance.

`kmalloc(size, mask)` reserves a memory area of size bytes and returns a void pointer to the start of the area. If insufficient memory is available (a very improbable situation in the kernel but one that must always be catered for), a null pointer is the result.

mask speciﬁes details about request:

```
• memory zone
• behavior of allocator (blocking/unblocking request, etc.)
• e.g. GFP_KERNEL, GFP_ATOMIC, GFP_DMA, etc
```

`alloc_pages() and __get_free_pages() : allocate pages, at low level`

`kmalloc() : allocate physically contiguous sequence of bytes`

for more information refer `professional linux kernel architecture by wolfgang mauerer`

Comment: What  i meant to ask was why these functions have different return values as in one return logical address and the other return pointer to the struct page.Why is that although both are using the same buddy allocator.

Comment: There are many places in the kernel where it is necessary to work with page structures.They are especially useful in any situation where you might be dealing with high memory, which does not have a constant address in kernel space.So `alloc_pages()` are using in these situations.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again , bit could you please tell me what do you mean by "constant address in kernel space". I understand the difference between virtual address , logical address and physical address and how they are related.So can you please relate constant address in kernel space with them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean kernel logical address,high memory for which kernel logical addresses do not exist, because it is beyond its range.Generally high memory is memory that is not permanently mapped into the kernel's address space,so only way to access it might be via the corresponding struct page structure.